# Table column headings based on different properties in object are not aligned in Angular using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, sass

I have a created a object with 2 properties person and vehicle both the properties consits of array of data. I have 2 different column headings for
person and vehicle properties. I display these 2 property data in tabular form. the problem is that the column headings for for both properties are not
aligned. can someone help me with this?

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
selector: "app-root",
templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent {
personColumns = ["Name", " Age", "Department"];
vehicleColumns = ["Model", "Color", "Company"]
values = {
person: [
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 28,
    department: "Accounting"
  },
  {
    name: "Max",
    age: 26,
    department: "Sports"
  },
  {
    name: "Rose",
    age: 24,
    department: "Arts"
  }
],
vehicle: [
{
  model: "SEDAN",
  color: "Red",
  compay: "Mercedes"
},
{
  model: "COUPE",
  color: "White",
  compay: "BMW"
},
{
  model: "SUV",
  color: "Yellow",
  compay: "AUDI"
}
]
};
}
```

In component.html file

```
<div *ngIf="values != []">
<span *ngIf="values.person">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="p-1" *ngFor="let column of personColumns">
          {{ column }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let value of values.person">
        <ng-container *ngIf="value.name != 'Max'">
          <td class="p-1">
            {{ value.name }}
          </td>
          <td class="p-1">
            {{ value.age }}
          </td>
          <td class="p-1">
            {{ value.department }}
          </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="value.name == 'Max'">
          <td class="p-1">
            {{ value.name }}
          </td>
          <td class="p-1">
            {{ value.age }}
          </td>
          <td class="p-1">
            {{ value.department + " changed to" + " IT" }}
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</span>

<span *ngIf="values.vehicle">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="p-1" *ngFor="let column of vehicleColumns">
          {{ column }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let value of values.vehicle">
        <ng-container *ngIf="value.model != 'SUV'">
          <td class="p-1">
            {{ value.model }}
          </td>
          <td class="p-1">
            {{ value.color }}
          </td>
          <td class="p-1">
            {{ value.compay }}
          </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="value.model == 'SUV'">
          <td class="p-1">
            {{ value.model }}
          </td>
          <td class="p-1">
            {{ value.color }}
          </td>
          <td class="p-1">
            {{ value.compay + " changed to" + " Ford" }}
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

In app.component.scss

```
@import "../styles.scss";

.table thead th {
vertical-align: top;
}

th {
white-space: nowrap;
cursor: pointer;
user-select: none;
color: grey;
}

table {
margin: 0;
font-family: "Lato";
font-size: 12px;
}

.table-responsive {
 min-height: 60px;
}

.cell {
max-width: 250px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.table thead th {
vertical-align: top;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It will be pretty difficult to adjust these values to be centered as they have different lengths and are from different tables. What I would suggest doing is to build a table with multiple headers, or even moving the table to the side so that this centered alignment does not bother you anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to use a single table to keep same length for every value**
For now you can use this template:

```
<div *ngIf="values != []">
<span *ngIf="values.person">
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="let column of personColumns">
                        {{ column }}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let value of values.person">
                    <ng-container *ngIf="value.name != 'Max'">
                        <td>
                            {{ value.name }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ value.age }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ value.department }}
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="value.name == 'Max'">
                        <td>
                            {{ value.name }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ value.age }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ value.department + " changed to" + " IT" }}
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <thead *ngIf="values.vehicle">
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="let column of vehicleColumns">
                        {{ column }}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody *ngIf="values.vehicle">
                <tr *ngFor="let value of values.vehicle">
                    <ng-container *ngIf="value.model != 'SUV'">
                        <td>
                            {{ value.model }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ value.color }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ value.compay }}
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="value.model == 'SUV'">
                        <td>
                            {{ value.model }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ value.color }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ value.compay + " changed to" + " Ford" }}
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
 </span>
```

Add bootstrap classes by including this in index.html file

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```